# Syntax Highlighting of an Embedded Language in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, syntax, visual-studio-2012, syntax-highlighting, mef

I'm using C# and Visual Studio 2012 to implement syntax highlighting of a language embedded in html (much like ASP code inside <% %>). So far, I've found out that I need to use  `IProjectionBuffer` to achieve this, but there are no examples of how to do this using MEF, apart from a somewhat vague description here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885240.aspx#projection. I tried to assign spans of text from the `ITextBuffer` that is "imported" through MEF to an `IProjectionBuffer`, but it had no effect.

Does anybody have any ideas as to how to proceed?

Comment: The sources of ASP.NET and the tools are open source (http://aspnet.codeplex.com/) you might find a few gems in there...

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in feature for this purpose I think. I used to deal with text highlighting in C# code with MEF with tags. I think you shold start with [Text.Classification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.classification%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

There is a lack of documentation sadly, but I think you should build a lexer or somthing similar for the lingual part [MSDN:DLR (features)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052.aspx) may can help you,

> The DLR allows language implementers to avoid creating lexical
>   analyzers, parsers, semantic analyzers, code generators, and other
>   tools that they traditionally had to create themselves.

detect the delimiters, and color it through classification.

Here is an [example project](https://github.com/tomasr/KeywordClassifier) to customize C# code displaying.